# Using a string variable to set a 'Class = new <string of Class()>'

Tags: c#, class

I have a three polymorphed classes. Based on user input the class should be set to that user's input. So the child class is decided by a user, and should make for 'class = new inputClass'. The snippet of code looks like:

```
public void characterGeneration(string classSelected)
    {
        foreach (string classInList in classes.ClassList)
        {
            if (classSelected == classInList)
            {
                PlayerOneStats = new Mage();
            }
        }

        PlayerOneStats.generateStats();
    }
```

Where it says `PlayerOneStats = new Mage();`, I want the `Mage()` to be the user input.

I've looked at Activator, Assembly, using Type, trying to cast over to the parent of `GenerateStats`, but nothing works. I've found many people saying it works, and one link that says it doesn't work. Can somebody please clear this up for me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the base class of `Mage` (and the other classes a user can select)?  You should be able to do this:

```
    public void characterGeneration(string classSelected)
    {
        foreach (string classInList in classes.ClassList)
        {
            if (classSelected == classInList)
            {
                PlayerOneStats = (GenerateStats)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("YourNamespace." + classSelected);
                break;
            }
        }

        PlayerOneStats.generateStats();
    }
```

Comment: PlayerOneStats = new (GenerateStats)Activator.CreateInstance(classSelected);

gives me 'Game.GenerateStats is a type but used like a variable

Comment: What would 'Type stat' be in the parameters?

Comment: Scratch that.  Try what I put up now.  Replace "YourNamespace" with the actual namespace your `Mage`, etc. classes are in.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you! I spent way too long trying to figure that out. I've had properties that i've pulled up by user input but couldn't figure out classes. Now it is settled and I am on my way to finishing this program. 

One last question, how would you compare the results of how you made it so I can call the classes vs. 'Activator.CreateInstace("assembly-name", "type-name")'. I couldn't figure out how to make the latter work; I do not know the assembly name and type name so I couldn't get it to work anyways, though it would be nice to know.

Comment: Also, can I give you a plus one rep somewhere? I'm new to this site.

Comment: The difference is that `Activator.CreateInstance("assembly-name", "type-name")` is generally used for types that are declared in a different assembly. Mine is assuming your types are in the same assembly as the `characterGeneration` method which is currently executing.

Comment: Click the up-arrow to the left of my answer. Also, if this did solve your problem, click the big hollow checkmark which should then color in green, saying this is the accepted solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure Activator doesn't work? `Activator.CreateInstace("assembly-name", "type-name")` seems like exactly what you want. What doesn't work?

Comment: I need to set PlayerOneStats = new "String of Class" and when I try to do PlayerOneStats = new Activator.CreateInstance(...) it tells me CreateInstance(...) is a method but used like a type. I need to have the new keyword in there to instantiate my (Mage/Warrior/Rogue) class correct?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue here. No, you don't need the `new` keyword when using `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: What would be my "assembly-name" and "type-name"?

Comment: type-name is the string you get. assembly name iis the assembly the type is defined in.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you include the namespace the type you want is contained in and this should work for you:

```
string classSelected = "testCode.Mage";
var player = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(classSelected));
```

Since `Activator.CreateInstance()` returns an `object` you will have to cast - in your case it would make sense to cast to an interface that all your player classes implement:

```
var player = (IPlayerCharacter) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(classSelected));
```